# Prime numbers equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Could you please help me for this proof :

Prove that there is no triplet of integers (x, y, z) prime to each other such that: $$x²+y² = 3z²$$

I tried to make a proof by contradiction...

Comment: Reduce mod $4$ to show that $z$ can’t be odd. Then conclude that if $(x,y,z)$ is an integer solution, so is $(x/2,y/2,z/2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RHS is divisible by $3$. If either $x$ or $y$ are $1$ or $-1$ modulo $3$ then $3$ will not divide the LHS. Hence $x$ and $y$ must be both $0$ modulo $3$ which implies the GCD of $x$ and $y$ must be at least $3$. Hence they can't be coprime.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! :))